# I want to clear the value of the shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have stored the username and the password in the sharedpreference.
And I am displaying the username in every activity like Welcome "Username".
But at the time of logout I have put one checkbox in the dialog box.If the check box is checked the sharedpreference value should be clear. So I don't know how to do it.Please help me out of it. Thank you.

Comment: You need to accept an answer when it helps solve ur problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method to clear the sharedpreferences is this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()

With this you dont delete the xml

```
Editor.clear();

Editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 16):

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
if (settings.contains("mykey")) {    
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.remove("mykey");
    editor.apply();    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [remove method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29) which is simple and described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29). The only parameter is the Key you have used to save this preference.

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st method

   ```
   Your_sharedprefrence_name..clear();
   Your_sharedprefrence_name.commit();
   ```
2. 2nd Method

   ```
    Your_sharedprefrence_name.clear().commit();
   ```
3. 3rd Method(When u want to clear the arraylist of sharedprefrence put it in loop)

   ```
   Your_sharedprefrence_name.remove(String.valueOf(i)).clear().commit();
   ```